# BMXAA0021E - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again

Tags: cron-task, maximo

The following message appears in the SystemOut for Maximo, usually shortly after starting the server:

> [16/08/16 12:30:05:468 BST] 00000037 SystemOut     O 16 Aug 2016 12:30:05:468 [ERROR] [MAXDEVSVR] [CID-CRON-32] BMXAA0021E - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.
>   psdi.util.MXAccessException: BMXAA0021E - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.
>       at psdi.server.SimpleCronTask.start(SimpleCronTask.java:549)
>       at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.callCronMethod(CronTaskManager.java:1585)
>       at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.access$400(CronTaskManager.java:87)
>       at psdi.server.CronTaskManager$CronThread.run(CronTaskManager.java:1948)

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this turns out to be related to the scheduled reports cron-task. The "Run As" user may be inactive or blocked.

You can either deactivate the cron-task instance for each report, change the user, or use the following SQL to remove the instances:

```
delete from CRONTASKINSTANCE where  exists(
select null from maxuser where userid = RUNASUSERID and status != 'ACTIVE'
);
```

Note that this query does not limit to the REPORTSCHEDULE cron-task so make sure you run a select beforehand to ensure that you aren't deleting something useful.